# Where is default cache directory for FilesystemAdapter in Symfony 3?

Tags: php, caching, symfony

I'm on Windows and looking for the location of the cache generated by `FileSystemAdapter`. I thought it would be in var/cache of the application directory but it doesn't look like as when I clear it, it's still using the cache.

Any idea where it could be?

Comment: If you didn't define the location a directory is created inside the system temporary directory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**[Filesystem Cache Adapter](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/cache/cache_pools.html#filesystem-cache-adapter)**

```
use Symfony\Component\Cache\Adapter\FilesystemAdapter;

$cache = new FilesystemAdapter(
    // the subdirectory of the main cache directory where cache items are stored
    $namespace = '',
    // in seconds; applied to cache items that don't define their own lifetime
    // 0 means to store the cache items indefinitely (i.e. until the files are deleted)
    $defaultLifetime = 0,
    // the main cache directory (the application needs read-write permissions on it)
    // if none is specified, a directory is created inside the system temporary directory
    $directory = null
);
```

> **note**: if none is specified, a directory is created inside the system
>   temporary directory.

Also see: [Removing Cache Items](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/cache/cache_pools.html#removing-cache-items)

Comment: Thank you, in my Cygwin shell the directory was in /tmp/symfony-cache/

Answer (score 5):

Checking in the [source code](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Cache/Adapter/FilesystemAdapter.php) of the class, the class use [this trait](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Cache/Adapter/FilesystemAdapterTrait.php#L27) and if you don't specify a directory, it will use the function [sys_get_temp_dir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sys-get-temp-dir.php) that return directory path used for temporary files.

For a Windows-based system could be:

```
C:\Windows\Temp
```

Hope this help