# How to add cache to a Twig App Extension?

Tags: php, symfony

I want to cache the results of a function which is called from a Twig template.

My template is simply `<h3>{{ cached_date() }}</h3>`

I've followed the [Cache Contracts tutorial](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/cache.html#cache-contracts) and now have this MVP:

```php
<?php
// src/Twig/AppExtension.php
namespace App\Twig;

use Symfony\Contracts\Cache\ItemInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Cache\Adapter\FilesystemAdapter;

use Twig\Extension\AbstractExtension;
use Twig\TwigFunction;

class AppExtension extends AbstractExtension
{

    public function getFunctions()
    {
        return [new TwigFunction('cached_date', [$this, 'get_date']),];
    }

    public function get_date() {
        $cache = new FilesystemAdapter();
        $value = $cache->get('cached_date', function (ItemInterface $item) {
            $item->expiresAfter(3600);
      
            $date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

            return $date;
      });

      return $value;

    }
}
```

I know that the function works, because if I return something other than `$value` then it is rendered into the template.

I've installed `composer require symfony/cache`.

What else am I missing?

Comment: Are you sure you have a writeable `temporary directory`? More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40811019/where-is-default-cache-directory-for-filesystemadapter-in-symfony-3)

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, my app required a *named* cache. This was solved by using

```php
$cache = new FilesystemAdapter("my_awesome_cache");
```